# R Shiny: passing reactive values to and from modules

Tags: r, shiny, module, syntax

My endgoal is to have an app where I put graphs in modules; I want to be able to zoom in one graph, and then the graph in the other module should update its horizontal axis range accordingly. I got this to work with two graphs, without using modules.

When I wanted to scale it to larger numbers of graphs, I decided to implement it as modules (this is new for me), but I can't get it to work. I have narrowed my problem down to a minimal example, not using graphs but numericInput. And that illustrates what I´m probably doing wrong, but I can´t figure out how to fix it.

I looked for other questions/answers, but I couldn't understand any answer so that it worked for me, in this case of two-directional communication.

I have a "global" numericInput. I have a module that also contains a numericInput. I call that module twice.
What I intend to do:

1. If I change the value in one of the modules and click the button, the global numericInput gets updated (that works).
2. Whenever the global numericInput gets updated, the numericInputs in the modules get updated. That doesn't happen.
3. When the app is started, some default value is set in the global numericInput, which needs to be "forwarded" to the module numericInputs.

I'm guessing the way I pass the input$toplevel to testServer is the culprit; clearly Shiny doesn't seem to think it needs to react on changes in the global numericInput. What do I need to do to fix this?

Here the code for the example (I hope it counts as minimal, this is my first time! ;)):

```
library(shiny)


testUI <- function(id) {
  tagList(
    numericInput(NS(id, "module"), "module", value = NULL),
    actionButton(NS(id,"button"), label = "send")
  )
}

testServer <- function(id,reactinput) {
  stopifnot(is.reactive(reactinput))
  
  moduleServer(id, function(input,output,session) {
    rval <- reactiveValues(num = reactinput)
    observeEvent(rval$num,{updateNumericInput(inputId = "module")})
    
    observeEvent(input$button, {
      rval$num <- input$module
    })
    return(reactive({rval$num}))
  }) 
}

testApp <- function() {
  ui <- fluidPage(
    numericInput("global", "global", value = 5),
    testUI("test1"),
    testUI("test2")
  )
  server <- function(input, output, session) {
    val1 <- testServer("test1",reactive(input$toplevel))
    observeEvent(val1(), {updateNumericInput(inputId = "global", value = val1())})

    val2 <-testServer("test2",reactive(input$toplevel))
    observeEvent(val2(), {updateNumericInput(inputId = "global", value = val2())})
  }
  shinyApp(ui, server)  
}

testApp()
```

Comment: On a first look, I think you need `rval <- reactiveValues(num = reactinput())` in the module server.  `reactinput` is the `reactive`, `reactinput()` is the `reactive`'s value.  So `reactinput` never changes in the body of the module.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple issues with your code. First, the global input has an `inputId` `global` not `toplevel`. Second, `reactinput` is a `reactive`. Hence, you have to use `reactinput()` to access the value. To this end I use an `observe` to update `rval` inside the module server. Third, when updating the numeric input in the module you have to pass the value of `rval` to the `value=` argument.

```
library(shiny)

testUI <- function(id) {
  tagList(
    numericInput(NS(id, "module"), "module", value = NULL),
    actionButton(NS(id, "button"), label = "send")
  )
}

testServer <- function(id, reactinput) {
  stopifnot(is.reactive(reactinput))

  moduleServer(id, function(input, output, session) {
    rval <- reactiveValues(num = NULL)
    observe({
      rval$num <- reactinput()
    })
    
    observeEvent(rval$num, {
      updateNumericInput(session, inputId = "module", value = rval$num)
    })

    observeEvent(input$button, {
      rval$num <- input$module
    })
    return(reactive({
      rval$num
    }))
  })
}

testApp <- function() {
  ui <- fluidPage(
    numericInput("global", "global", value = 5),
    testUI("test1"),
    testUI("test2")
  )
  server <- function(input, output, session) {
    val1 <- testServer("test1", reactive(input$global))
    observeEvent(val1(), {
      updateNumericInput(inputId = "global", value = val1())
    })

    val2 <- testServer("test2", reactive(input$global))
    observeEvent(val2(), {
      updateNumericInput(inputId = "global", value = val2())
    })
  }
  shinyApp(ui, server)
}

testApp()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! The naming was really stupid, I changed the name while writing this post to make the question clearer. Seems I forgot two changes…Oops… I tried reactinput with and without brackets-but it never occurred to me that it required the observe. That is probably where my real app fails. Now, I can go to implementation!